# MySQL How to check if an value is already in the results?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a complicated problem.

How can I force MySQL to replace the first "command.deagle2" (Mode 1) with the second "command.deagle2" (Mode 0) ?

I simply show you the code and I hope you can help me.

Here my code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    `right`.`name` AS `Right`,
    1 AS `Mode`

FROM    
    `user`

INNER JOIN
    `user_group` ON
        `user`.`id` = `user_group`.`user_id`

INNER JOIN
    `group` ON
        `user_group`.`group_id` = `group`.`id`

INNER JOIN
    `group_right` ON
        `group`.`id` = `group_right`.`group_id`

INNER JOIN
    `right` ON
        `group_right`.`right_id` = `right`.`id`

WHERE
    `user`.`username` = 'Dominik'

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT
    `right`.`name` AS `Right`,
    `user_right`.`mode` AS `Mode`

FROM
    `user`,
    `right`,
    `user_right`

WHERE
    `user`.`id` = `user_right`.`user_id` AND
    `right`.`id` = `user_right`.`right_id` AND
    `user`.`username` = 'Dominik'
```

This query returns the following results:

```
Right           | Mode
-----------------------
command.deagle  | 1
command.deagle2 | 1
command.gmx     | 1
command.givegun | 1
command.deagle2 | 0
```

Sample dataset: http://pastebin.com/m5LHsDRi

I already saw that there is an REPLACE keyword, but I dont really know how to use it properly.

Thanks for your Time.

Dominik

Comment: it's hard to help without a sample dataset

Comment: I'll provided an sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it your "mode" column constitutes a priority, and you want the only the distinct value of "Right" with the lowest-numbered priority in your result set.

Try wrapping this query around the query you gave us:

```
  SELECT Right,
         MIN(Mode) AS Mode,
    FROM (
      /* your big query */
         ) AS q
   GROUP BY Right
```

That will give you what you want. By the way, you can remove the `DISTINCT` keyword from your main query if you do this; the `GROUP BY` will fill the same purpose.

Comment: Hi Ollie. Its not that what i really wanted. But First of all, you solved another problem of mine with it. Many thanks :). But what i need is an statement, which replaces the first occurrence of "command.deagle2" (Mode 1) with the second occurrence of "command.deagle2" (Mode 0) so that the Right with Mode 0 remains.

Comment: I don't get it. Are you trying somehow to modify your resultset? Or are you trying to update the contents of one or more tables? Keep in mind that SQL doesn't offer the concept of "first" unless you use `ORDER BY` clauses; the order of rows in result sets returned by SQL queries is formally unpredictable in the absence of ordering instructions. That's why they're called result *sets.*  `REPLACE` is good for string manipulation within individual rows of a result set.

Comment: Its the first concept. I could archieve this with PHP but i thought it would be more clean in complete SQL code. I'll keep searching. Many thanks for your Answer.